# Swap TextView text to another TextView Text in the same activity

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am making kind of guessing picture game. When I select one word i.e **A**, it should move upward empty **TextView**. So, when I select **A** from above box it should move to its original down one **TextView**.

Basically, all I am doing is by clicking moving A from lower box(TextView) to upper box(TextView).
On clicking the upper box(TextView) A should move back to the lower box.

I am new to android and learning something new. Just need a little bit help or concepts so I can move on.

These are two TextView I am using to swap one Text into other.

**Using for Upper TextView**
TextView btnA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.upbtnA)

**Using for down TextView**
TextView btnA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.downbtnA)

Comment: Just so I understand this, you want to swap the values between 2 textView?

Comment: Can you make a simple sketch of what you want to do? Arrow diagrams will be enough

Comment: @Nero I am on mobile right now. Yes I want to swap values between 2 textview. That is what I want to do.

Comment: You might want to declare second TextView as btnB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String temp = btn1.getText().toString();
                btn1.setText(btn2.getText().toString());
                btn2.setText(temp);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I will try that method and will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thank you so much, it is working perfectly. I am so happy. :):):)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple as you are only working with .getText and .setText syntax.

First you get the text

```
String txt1 = textview1.getText().toString();

String txt2 = textview2.getText().toString
```

Then you set the text

```
Textview1.setText(txt2);
Textview2.setText(txt1);
```

But you will also have to implement an onClickListener so if user clicks on either text, it will carry out that function so...

```
Textview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener){
  //get the text and set the text
```

}

Same for the second textview

Please note I'm also on my phone so the output of the code might be confusing

Comment: @ Nero Thank you, Sir.

Comment: Your welcome, let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: Sure. Thanks again.